# How to use ASP.Net 5 CreatedAtAction

Tags: http-post, asp.net-core

I'm trying to do an HttpPost to create an entity and I want to return a 201 created with the location header set to https://mysite/api/entity/1. I can't figure out how to do this while returning an IActionResult.

Calling it like this

```
return CreatedAtAction("Get", new { id = entity.Id }, "/{id}");
```

I get https://mysite/api/entity?id=11

I can't figure out how to get what I want.

Answer (score 2):

I assign a route name to the Get action and reference it by name to make this work.  For example:

```
    // GET api/values/5
    [HttpGet("{id}", Name="GetAction")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/values
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
        return this.CreatedAtRoute(
          "GetAction", new { id = 5 }, new { id = 5 });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Roberto, I'll try that tomorrow

Comment: you can also use - CreatedAtAction("<<ExactMethodNameofGetCall>>", new { id = entity.Id }, entity);